# Column chart horizontal axis misplaced

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex-charts

I am using Flex 3 Column chart component. In this, I have a custom container which in minimized(25% of maximized screen) mode, it is not showing horizontal axis properly(in short not utilizing the whole container area properly) and hence H axis is cut on left and right. If I maximize container, it shows perfect graph.

Attached the image.
[image: Column chart not using proper user area]

Comment: the whole code would be helpoful.Can you share the mxml components code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem. 
The length of labels on X axis were causing this issue. I reduced the length of labels and it worked fine.